# Sending "this" keyword into an object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'foobar',

    param: {
        x: this.id // Will be "undefined"
    }
});
```

Is there any way making use of `this`, that can make `this.param.x` pointing to, or has the same value with `this.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like that,

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  id: 'foobar',

  initialize: function () {
      this.param = { x: this.id };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the object's `this` in a static declaration.  You can set that value in a method call or in the constructor with code, but not in a static declaration.